# Why do Ubuntu & Lubuntu 14.04 have different support periods?

Tags: lubuntu, lts, 14.04

This doesn't make sense. I rather have LXDE as my desktop so I use Lubuntu.  But why is Ubuntu 14.04's LTS support period 5 years when Lubuntu 14.04's is only 3 years?  Do they not use the same repositories and therefore get all the same security updates?  This just doesn't add up!

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Flavors such as Lubuntu are build by volunteers and as such supporting releases for users is dependent on the amount of volunteers available.

Being relatively new (2001), Lubuntu did not have an LTS release at all for 12.04. This time around Lubuntu feels like they can support their users for 3 years.

You're right that they use the same repositories, but support will depend on the package. So if you use say, Firefox, then you're probably good as that package is widely used and support is shared with plain Ubuntu.

As with all open projects one of the best ways to help is to [volunteer](http://lubuntu.net/)!